# Sibling Component communication of Same component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a `Banner` component which shows a different images based on props e.g a page which consist of 3-4 banners would look like:

```
<Banner type="wide"></Banner>
<Banner type="small"></Banner>
<Banner type="medium"></Banner>
```

When `user` clicks on the banner, I need to propagate the event to all sibling components present on that page. So in this case a `Banner` component.

But it's after all a same component behind the scene which is already `mounted`.

How to share propagate data in this instance?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Do the banners change state as the result of one of them being clicked? If so, maybe the parent could pass a prop to all of them when one of them emits a "click"event.

Comment: @DavidWeldon : You meant child -> Parent ->  all children's ( broadcast ) ?

Comment: child emits a click event to parent -> parent alters state to know which child was clicked -> parent passes the id/name/etc of the last clicked `Banner` to each child. Each child could `watch` for changes to the last clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `emit`

Using emit is rather straight foward

**Note**: The `emit('myEmitEvent')` method won't target only sibling components, any component that registers for the `@myEmitEvent` will get the message

```
<!-- Banner.vue -->
<!-- note that this is not working code, but a means to demonstrate -->
<!-- how to use the 'emit' method -->

<template>
    <app>
        <img @click="notify" @bannerEvent="subscribe"/>
    </app>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            notify () {
                this.$emit('bannerEvent', somePayloadIfYouWant)
            },

            subscribe (payload) {
                console.log(payload)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you are using the vuex store you can use that for more indirect communication, by using the `computed` property, but that is a bit more contrived if you aren't using the `vuex` store